# Missing "Server Certificates" icon in IIS10

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, iis-10

I want to create a CSR file in windows server but Server Certificates is missing. The picture below shows it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Server Certificate is missing if you connect to another machine remotely.

That's by design. To manage certificates remotely, you need to use Remote Desktop Connection or other approaches (like PowerShell).